# Java Sorting arrayList based on textField

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Background:
Im creating this Employee Records application, where you can add a persons ID, First Name, Last Name, Salary and Start Date. It consists of a "Add" button, "Remove" button, "List" Combo box, and an output.

What I need help with is sorting the arrayList by ID and displaying the sorted version in the output.
    `public class EmployeeRecordsView extends FrameView{

```
    ArrayList <one> myList = new ArrayList <one>();
    //List<one> records = new ArrayList<one>();
    String iD, first, last, salary, startDate;
    public EmployeeRecordsView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
      //Cut out code
    }

    class one {
        String iD, first, last, salary, startDate;
        one (String _iD, String _first, String _last, String _salary, String
        _startDate){
            iD = _iD;
            first = _first;
            last = _last;
            salary = _salary;
            startDate = _startDate;
        }
    }
    private void btnAddMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
       one emp;
       iD = id.getText();
       first = firstName.getText();
       last = lastName.getText();
       salary = sal.getText();
       startDate = start.getText();
       emp = new one(iD, first, last, salary, startDate);
       myList.add(emp);
    }                                   

    private void btnRemoveMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
        String remove;
        remove = id.getText();
        myList.remove(remove);
    }                                      

    private void btnExitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        System.exit(0);
    }                                    


    private void jComboBox1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
     if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "Order of Addition"){
            String temp="";

        for (int x=0; x<=myList.size()-1; x++) {
            temp = temp + "ID#: " + myList.get(x).iD + ", "
                    + "First Name: " + myList.get(x).first + ", "
                    + "Last Name: " + myList.get(x).last + ", "
                    + "Annual Salary: " + myList.get(x).salary + ", "
                    + "Starting Date: " + myList.get(x).startDate + "\n";
        }
        outPut.setText(temp);
        }

     if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem() == "ID"){
         String temp="";
        for (int x=0; x<=myList.size()-1; x++) {
                  temp = temp + "ID#: " + myList.get(x).iD + ", "
                    + "First Name: " + myList.get(x).first + ", "
                    + "Last Name: " + myList.get(x).last + ", "
                    + "Annual Salary: " + myList.get(x).salary + ", "
                    + "Starting Date: " + myList.get(x).startDate + "\n";
        }
        outPut.setText(temp);
     }`
    }
```

Comment: [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Where do I put that?

Comment: When do you want to sort the list?

Comment: You shouldn't use MouseListeners with JButtons. Use ActionListeners as that's what they're for.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok got it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Im using swing, so I just right click the button and press the mouseClicked button

Comment: @MadProgrammer I says that the variable Comparator cannot be found

Comment: You need to define a `Comparator` of you own, which knows how to compare the individual `one` objects.  Read the linked Java Docs

Comment: Conor that makes no sense at all. Just because you can do something doesn't mean that you **should** do something. Except for read a tutorial -- you definitely should read the Swing JButton tutorial before making more statements like that.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I meant Netbeans design window

Comment: I know exactly what you meant. And I reiterate: You should **not** be using a MouseListener on a Swing JButton with only a very few exceptions. Me entiendes? And again, read the tutorial to gain some Java Swing knowledge. Using NetBeans blindly is not the way to learn (as you're finding out).

Comment: @ConorWatt The read the tutorials to understand the event handlers you should be using.  It is recommended to use `ActionListener` for buttons, not `MouseListener`, as these will be notified when the user presses [Enter] (and on some look and feels [Space]) as will as when the click it with the mouse

Comment: Exactly as @MadProgrammer says. Also you can't get the actionCommand from a MouseListener and *can* from an ActionListener. A MouseListener will not respect your attempt to disable a button, an ActionListener will. Using a MouseListener here will limit your ability to use the button fully.

Comment: I get that I am better off using an ActionListener, but for my online course we are using MouseListeners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), which will allow you to sort a `List` in a customised manner through the use of the `Comparator`.

So, based on a slight modification to you `one` class, to included a getter to retrieve the `iD` value

```
class One {

    String iD, first, last, salary, startDate;

    One(String _iD, String _first, String _last, String _salary, String _startDate) {
        iD = _iD;
        first = _first;
        last = _last;
        salary = _salary;
        startDate = _startDate;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return iD;
    }
}
```

You could use...

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<One>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(One o1, One o2) {
        return o1.getID().compareTo(o2.getID());
    }
});
```

Now note, this will sort the ID's in natural order, that is `1` will not appear before `10`, this is how `String` sorting works...

Comment: One the very first line would I write implements Comparator <one> beside extends FrameView>?

Comment: @ConorWatt: no, don't have your GUI implement Comparator.

Comment: Would I put Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<one>() {

    public int compare(one o1, one o2) {
        return o1.getID().compareTo(o2.getID());
    }
}); Inside or outside the last for statment?

Comment: You should put it where you want the list to be sorted, presumably after it's been updated and before you want to display the results